# setcookie on WordPress Page Template

Tags: themes, cookies

I am having an issue with setcookie.
I need to set a cookie on a page action (form).

I have tried on the template file, but not working.

then find out if I set it from functions.php with init hook, it's working.

then I put condition like

```php
if(is_page_template('mytemplate.php')){...
```

then it's not working.

how can I do that?

here is my code.

```php
add_action( 'init', 'hello_my_cookie' );

function hello_my_cookie() {
    if(is_page_template('mytemplate.php')){
        if(isset($_POST['GGmyCookie'])){
            setcookie( 'myCookie','Hello Cookie!', time()+3600);
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fails because the `init` hook is far too early to call `is_page_template`. Conditionals such as this function use the main query to decide their value, but WordPress hasn't created the main query yet.

The earliest hook you can safely do this is `template_redirect`.

Comment: Thank you!
but is there any other way to do this without calling the init hook?

I have tried to set the cookie from the template file. but it does not work.

Can you suggest any other way?

Comment: Thank you! it worked!